# Multiple objects, different behavior

Tags: c++, graphics, shader, hlsl, directx-11

I am trying to build a Tetris game with DirectX 11.1.
I can render a tank(boundary) and piece(I shape, t shape...) on the screen using simple triangle strips. I can also move the position of these objects using constant buffer of the shader.

The problem is that I bound the vertices with one buffer.
This causes the tank and pieces move together, which is not a desirable behavior.
I want to move only pieces, not the tank.

How do I separate two objects?
Should I create multiple buffers for each objects?
If so, do I have to render multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to handle this problem. You should keep in mind that you desired situation is having a separate transformation for each object and apply each transformation separately. You probably want to have control over one object at the time, but still you would like the rest of your object to be transformed the way they were placed (correct rotation and translation).

It is possible to create a separate buffer for each object and render each of them separately. You will end up having a lot of small buffers but this situation is probably the easiest one when you consider creating new objects and destroying the old ones. However, if you really think about it, will it be convenient when you destroy one line on blocks and then, need to update all buffers containing at least one block in this line? Think about it.

Now, the other approach is to have one buffer, that you'll update only when there's a new object created, or when objects are destroyed. You can draw only part of the buffer, using

```
ID3D11DeviceContext::Draw(VertexCount,StartVertexLocation)
```

In such a situation you will have a separate transformation matrix for each Draw call, but you keep your objects in one buffer.

Finally there's one more solution that allows you to render everything with one call, which is, storing all objects in one buffer, the same way as in the previous example. This time, however each time an object move, is created or destroyed you need to update this buffer. In this solution you don't store transformations for ALL objects. These transformations are already applied to all objects. But in this solution you need to update them in your C++ code on the CPU. There won't be many transformations going on so it should be efficient.